# WebInvoke Method = *

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on a project where a previous developer used a * for the Method of a WebInvoke.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", UriTemplate = "/Path", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void SetPath(PathInfo pathInfo);
```

I am wondering what the * is for - if anything. I was expecting GET, PUT, POST, etc... not star. Initially I was thinking default (POST), but there is no reason to use * if the it is the same as default.

MSDN does not seem to address it ([MSDN WebInvokeAttribute.Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.method(v=vs.100).aspx)), but they don't really address any of the methods except POST which is the default.

This post ([Implementing Method](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37650ab4-f3cb-4f2f-aa65-d94f218ea992/implementing-methodoptions?forum=wcf)) seems to indicate that the * should be used with the OPTIONS method as the UriTemplate. So, I am just trying to figure out if he is incorrect or if his code is valid in which case I would like to know what it means.

Comment: i'm guessing its for any method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decompiled the `System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior` which uses `WebInvoke`and you can see that this is just a wildcard action matching everything.

```
public class WebHttpBehavior : IEndpointBehavior, IWmiInstanceProvider
{
    internal const string GET = "GET";
    internal const string POST = "POST";
    internal const string WildcardAction = "*";
    internal const string WildcardMethod = "*";
```

This is a **catch all** behavior

Answer (score 0):

Using WebInvoke(method="*"... is the way to support CORS requests (Preflight, method='OPTIONS') from the browser. Using '*' on your service method will route the CORS preflight request into your service method (in addition to the get/post/put etc.) and will let you handle the preflight. Otherwise, your method will not be called on preflight requests, and the preflight will fail (in the browser)